# tensorflow assert element tf.where

Tags: tensorflow, z-index

I have 2 matrix with shape:

```
pob.shape = (2,49,20)  
rob.shape = np.zeros((2,49,20))
```

and I want to get the index of pob's elements which has value !=0. So in numpy I can do this:

```
x,y,z = np.where(pob!=0)
```

eg:

```
x = [2,4,7]  
y = [3,5,5]  
z = [3,5,6]
```

I want to change value of rob:

```
rob[x1,y1,:] = np.ones((20))
```

How can i do this with tensorflow objects?
I tried to use tf.where but I can't get the index value out of tensor obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tf.range()` and `tf.meshgrid()` to create index matrices, then use `tf.where()` with your condition on them to obtain the indices which meet it. However, the tricky part would come next: you can't easily assign values to a tensor based on indices in TF (`my_tensor[my_indices] = my_values`).

A workaround for your problem ("for all `(i,j,k)`, if `pob[i,j,k] != 0` then `rob[i,j] = 1`") could be as follows:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

# Example values for demonstration:
pob_val = [[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]], [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
pob = tf.constant(pob_val)
pob_shape = tf.shape(pob)
rob = tf.zeros(pob_shape)

# Get the mask:
mask = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(pob, 0), tf.uint8)

# If there's at least one "True" in mask[i, j, :], make all mask[i, j, :] = True:
mask = tf.cast(tf.reduce_max(mask, axis=-1, keepdims=True), tf.bool)
mask = tf.tile(mask, [1, 1, pob_shape[-1]])

# Apply mask:
rob = tf.where(mask, tf.ones(pob_shape), rob)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    rob_eval = sess.run(rob)
    print(rob_eval)
    # [[[0. 0. 0.]
    #   [1. 1. 1.]
    #   [1. 1. 1.]]
    #
    #  [[1. 1. 1.]
    #   [0. 0. 0.]
    #   [0. 0. 0.]]]
```